# Instantiating object with full name

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, compilation

quick theoric question. I have the following code:

```
if (partnership != null && partnership.UseCustomNotifier)
{
    //some behavior
}
else
{
    Integration.Protocol.Client.Notifier protocolNotifier = new Integration.Protocol.Client.Notifier();
}
```

I have two implementations for partnership that are chosen using reflection. **Integration.Protocol** is not in the usings. Implementation should be chosen dynamically; thing is, if I comment that last line (the instantiation of protocolNotifier), it will only chose one implementation (the one that does not come from the **Integration.Protocol**, because is the only one available). Otherwise, it will be chosen dynamically using reflection.

I know that this code sucks (I've improved it already), but I was curious on why this behavior was ocurring. I would guess that when the solution compiles before running, it checks that line where protocolNotifier is instantiated and adds the using on compilation time. Is this correct? Does it only happen within the scope of the method? Or the whole class? I am curious on how the .NET compiler works in those situations.

Comment: What do you mean by 'dynamically'.  The code you are showing does not have any reflection in it, but the code does look like a factory method/class.  That class isn't available anymore because you removed it from the method (I assume).  I guess what I am getting at is that the code you posted doesn't match your question. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: It doesn't add the `using` at compile time.`using <namespace>` is just there to save you from having to type the fully qualified name every time. Compiled IL code uses the fully qualified name. Have a look at your IL code and see for yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

- `partnership` is an object of a type that is chosen by using reflection to find all available classes with that name (we'll call it `Partnership`) and creating an object of the found type
- The `Integration.Protocol` namespace has a class called `Partnership` (or whatever it's actually called), but there is also another class called `Partnership` in either this project's code or some other library that you're already using elsewhere
- Depending on if you include that last line or not, your reflection code picks one or the other

If I'm correct in that, then I believe the behaviour you're seeing is simply because it's loading the `Integration.Protocol` library (assuming that is a separate DLL and not actually part of the current project code).

If you show us the code of how you set `partnership`, then we can confirm this. But if I'm correct, then if you don't use `Integration.Protocol` in that last line, then that library simply isn't loaded, and your reflection code won't find anything from that library.

It's not that "adding the `using` on compilation time", because `using` statements just allow you to not include the namespace when referring to classes. It doesn't have anything to do with whether libraries are loaded at runtime or not.